# Access custom functions within the Firefox Addon SDK main.js file?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

Why can't I access custom functions with the Firefox Addon SDK?

In my example code below, clicking context menu Sub Item 1 doesn't work; It refers to custom function `verifyTest()` but returns a ReferenceError: verifyTest is undefined. Clicking Sub Item 2 which directs to built-in function `alert()` works well.

I also tried with self.postMessage (and onMessage) but no success.. What do I have to do to access (or define) my custom functions that are required for my addon to work?

```
///// Content in main.js

function verifyTest() {
    alert('test1');
}

var script1 = 'self.on("click", function(node, data){'+
             '   verifyTest();'+
             '});';

var script2 = 'self.on("click", function(){'+
             '   alert(\'test2\');'+
             '});';

var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
cm.Menu({
  label: "Main Item",
  context: cm.SelectorContext("body"),
  items: [
    cm.Item({ label: "Sub Item 1", context: cm.SelectorContext("input[type=text]"), contentScript: script1, data: "item1" }),
    cm.Item({ label: "Sub Item 2", context: cm.SelectorContext("input[type=text]"), contentScript: script2, data: "item2" })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `verifyTest` is defined in the context of `main.js` not `script1`.

One solution is to put `verifyTest` inside `script1` (as quoted text).

A better solution would be to create a file `script1.js` (or other meaningful name) with this content:

```
function verifyTest() {
    alert('test1');
}

self.on("click", function(node, data){
    verifyTest();
});
```

and use `contentScriptFile` instead of `contentScript` to load it (see [Loading Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts)).

```
cm.Item({ label: "Sub Item 1", context: cm.SelectorContext("input[type=text]"), contentScriptFile: require("sdk/self").data.url("script1.js"), data: "item1" }),
```

This makes it more readable and maintainable and avoids bugs of using vars/functions defined in different contexts.